# How to print a Ruby Array on one line

Tags: ruby

I have an array, and I need to print it out all on one line:

```
numbers = Array[[2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9]
```

Instead of separate lines how can I code this? I heard `Array.join('')` but I tried this code and it wouldn't run.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "[ask]" and the linked pages
"[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)". When asking, we'd like to see evidence of your effort. WIthout that it looks like you didn't try, which is off-topic. We also need an example of your desired output.

Comment: "wouldn't run" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? What is the code you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 4):

Always remember that the Ruby manual is your friend. If you read the manual for [`Array#join`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join) you will find some good candidates:

> ```
> join(p1 = v1) public
> ```
>
> Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string, separated by the given `separator`. If the `separator` is `nil`, it uses current `$,`. If both the separator and `$,` are `nil`, it uses an empty string.
>
> ```
> [ "a", "b", "c" ].join        #=> "abc"
> [ "a", "b", "c" ].join("-")   #=> "a-b-c"
> ```

So, now we can try:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
puts numbers.join(" ")
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
p numbers
```

This will print your array on a single line (which will obviously overflow depending on your window width).

Answer (score 0):

You can use either method

```
puts numbers.join(', ');
```

or

```
puts numbers.inspect
```

Comment: While technically this will output the numbers on one line, it'll also result with them concatenated into one long number `2445579`, which is hardly useful. Also, it's idiomatic to use `[1,2,3]` over `Array[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @theTinMan, I agree with your comment so I updated the answer to reflect this and added the inspect method as an alternative.